# Filter list of dataclass instances based on specified attribute

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, magic-methods

Suppose I have a dataclass

```
@dataclass
class Person:
   
    name: str
    birthday: str
```

And I create some instances with these lists:

```
names = np.array(['John', 'Max', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Max', 'Alice'])
bithdays = np.array(['June', 'August', 'June', 'August', 'December', 'January'])
persons = np.column_stack((names, bithdays))

persons = [Person(*person) for person in persons]
```

Now I want to filter my list based on a specific attribute. Say, I want to get all persons with the same name. But another time I might want to get the persons with the same birthday.
Or I might even want to filter on a specific attribute and a specific value, so maybe get all persons who were born in June.

My idea is to somehow override the `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods to provide such flexibility. I guess this is the right approach. Since I have no experience with this I would appreciate some hints or ideas on how to create such a flexible filter elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pythonic ways for achieving this. First would be to use the [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) builtin function:

```
same_names = filter(lambda p: p.name == "Alice", persons)
```

And second is to use list/generator comprehensions:

```
same_names = [p for p in persons if p.name == "Alice"]  # list
# or
same_names = (p for p in persons if p.name == "Alice")  # generator
```

The advantage of *filter* and *generator* is that it does not create a new list, but create a way to iterate over the existing list and apply the condition you need on the fly.